# copy value from first row in a data frame and rename column

Tags: r, dataframe

How would one copy the value from the first row in a data frame, rename the column name with that value and then delete the row?

E.g.

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
a   b   c   d   e
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4
```

to

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4
```

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself? Why did it not work? And how did you end up with a dataframe in this format? Might be better to solve this upstream instead of downstream.

Comment: I am guessiing that this might be a case of not specifying `header=TRUE` in the `read.table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
#create a vector of the first row values and replace the column names
names(df) <-  unlist(df[1,])
#remove the first row
df <- df[-1,]
```

Output:

```
> df
  a b c d e
2 1 1 1 1 1
3 2 2 2 2 2
4 3 3 3 3 3
5 4 4 4 4 4
```

Then again if you ended up with the wrong column names while using `read.table` or something similar it might be worth having a look there.

As per @Roland 's comment, if the data.frame after the above conversion consists of numbers that are of character type (not factor) as a result of the character first row, using the following will convert them to the appropriate types:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert)
```

Comment: If you do this, you should apply `type.convert` afterwards.

Comment: @Roland That's a nice addition indeed. I suspect this is not the OP's real data.frame however.